# Get Appstore information of previous app versions

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, info

My issue is about the handling of itunes connect. Actually I uploaded a 1.1 version of an app. I changed the texts in the description and I want to compare the effect of the newer app store presence. But therefore I need the information which were written before version 1.1.

Is there a way to get the keywords, descriptions, ad text, etc. from the previous versions which were released via itunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.app.id"` url. In which you have to set bundle id of your app and you get dict of your app info.

```
 let str = "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.app.id"
 let url = URL(string: str)
 Alamofire.request(url! ,  method: .get).responseJSON { (dataResponse) in

        print(dataResponse.result.value)
 }
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried but I only get the current information of version 1.1 when I enter the bundle ID. Can I trick it with some special suffixes?

Comment: do you want to get details for others versions of your apps rather then current??

Comment: Yes. In this case from the version right before the current.

Comment: As the question title tells!